# Number of voters that must be interviewed in order to predict result

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics

I found an interesting question in a textbook for school kids:

**Estimate the minimum number of eligible voters that one must interview in order to be able to predict with a probability $\ge90\%$ the election result for a particular party with an error of $\le1\%$.**

I think this must be solved applying multinomial or multivariate hypergeometric distributions with unknown number of parties.

The question is translated from a German textbook and the original quote is as follows:

> Man schätze die Anzahl der Wahlberechtigten, die man mindestens befragen muß, um mit einer Wahrscheinlichkeit von 90% oder mehr das Wahlergebnis für eine bestimmte Partei mit einem Fehler von höchstens 1% vorhersagen zu können.
>
> Franz Heigl, Jürgen Feuerpfeil: Stochastik. ein Lehr- und Arbeitsbuch, München 1987, p.179

Comment: I corrected your (otherwise perfect) translation slightly. "Man schätze" is a subjunctive which here carries the sense of an imperative (technically, it's the [jussive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussive_mood)); hence "Estimate", not "One estimates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fancy distributions are required for a problem like this; it is always assumed that the sample size is large enough that successive draws from the population can be regarded as approximately independent. In particular, we don't need to reach for a multinomial distribution, because by focusing on one party we have translated the problem to a binomial consideration (a respondent either does, or does not, prefer that party).

At its core, this is about deriving a $90\%$ confidence interval for a population proportion $p$. By a common statistical result, the confidence interval has the form
$$\hat p \pm z_{\alpha / 2} \sqrt{ p (1-p) / n}$$
where $\hat p$ is the sample estimate of the proportion, $z_{\alpha/2}$ is a critical value from the normal distribution (in this case, $1.645$), $p$ is the true population proportion, and $n$ is the sample size. The margin of error is the term on the right side of the $\pm$ sign, so our task is to make
$$1.645 \sqrt{p (1 - p)} / \sqrt n < 0.01. $$
Note that the worst case for the expression $\sqrt{p (1 - p)}$ occurs when $ p = 1/2$, so we need
$$\sqrt n > \frac{1.645 \cdot \sqrt{(1/2)^2}}{0.01}$$
and solving for $n$ gives an answer of $\fbox{6766}$ people (rounding up to guarantee we see the desired confidence).

Comment: This confidence interval is only some chapters later introduced in the textbook. Are there other ways to solve it?

Comment: Fair enough. If by this point in the text students already have the Central Limit Theorem, that's really all that's needed; a binomial variable is well approximated by a normal distribution with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$, so the inner $90\%$ of the curve is well approximated by $np \pm z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$, and we're basically back to where we started.

Comment: My last comment was in error; the variance of the binomial is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, and we then need to divide all that by $n$ to recover something resembling the confidence interval.